# Warning of "unresponsive script" in Firefox

Tags: firefox, javascript, firefox-extensions

I am getting warning in Firefox about Unresponsive Script for the last few days and all commands lock-up.
The script is said to be:

```
https://apis.google.com/_/scs/.colq-IFOizNwoQA/cb=gapi./loaded_0:`16
```

I do not know how to get additional info.

Comment: Please provide more info about this script. The link you provided isn't working.

Comment: I will try to see if I can Copy/Paste any others that show up; & send them on as they do. I'm utterly-new at all this.

Comment: This is about the 5th day that I've truncated use of my computer.

Comment: If everything hangs so that you cannot even get anything from your screen, post a screenshot of your screen. Without that nobody will able to help you, as your description is very vague.

Comment: tHIS IS THE LATEST ONE:

Comment: A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://secure-ds.serving-sys.c…urstingScript/SZMKFLVPAIDBR.js:6

Comment: A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://secure-ds.serving-sys.c…urstingScript/SZMKFLVPAIDBR.js:6

Comment: http://secure-ds.serving-sys.c…urstingScript/SZMKFLVPAIDBR.js:6
--

Comment: First of all you should have told that this script error plagues Firefox. Secondly, do you use Ubuntu? Most pages describing ds.serving-sys.com popup are related to Windows.

Comment: I use FF, on U/L. Never blogged before. Don't know how to Stop script. I do not know how to make screenshot, let alone post it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue with Firefox type in its address bar `about:support` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the top right corner of the opened page you will see the button which runs Firefox in safe mode with disabled add-ons. Press it. Firefox will restart in safe mode.

Now type in its address bar `about:addons` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will see the full list of add-ons installed in your browser. Analyze all of them. You can check their details by pressing "More" link on each of them. There's the bothersome add-on among them, related to `ds.serving-sys.com` ad site. It may be called **UNiDealsa**. There may be other unwanted add-ons. Remember their names and restart Firefox - it will start in normal mode.

As soon as it started, go once again to `about:addons` page and disable the add-on(s) which you estimated as undesirable. Use your browser for some time. If script error has stopped and you haven't disabled some valuable add-on(s), then you can remove the disabled addon(s) forever.

It is also recommended to clean your profile from the leftovers of this bothersome add-on. This can be done on the same `about:support` page. There's "Refresh Firefox" button for that.
But remember, some of your settings will be reverted to the initial state, so check this [article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) at Mozilla site to estimate are you ready to perform that.